# How to know whether there is any overlap in a collection of periods using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of periods `[FromDate, ToDate]`.

I would know whether there is any overlap between a given period and the periods in the collection.

I've already started with this:

```
 // periodToCheck is the given item
 bool conflict = Periods.Any(p => ((p.FromDate >= periodToCheck.fromDate && 
                                    p.FromDate <= periodToCheck.toDate)
                                  ||
                                   (p.ToDate >= periodToCheck.fromDate && 
                                    p.ToDate <= periodToCheck.toDate))
                             );
```

The problem that it does not cover all the situation, for example:

```
[2010.1.1], [2010.1.31]
[2010.1.5], [2010.1.6] // Is valid in the query in spite of it is not valid 
                       // (because there is intersection).
```

And if I discuss more situation I  think the query will become more complicated.

I wonder if you could help me with the simplest valid way.

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approach it this way instead: There is no intersaction if the check date's todate < the from date, or the check date's fromdate > the to date.  This is assuming check.from <= check.to.

```
Periods.Any(p => !(check.ToDate < p.FromDate || check.FromDate > p.ToDate));
```

or (after unwrapping the negative):

```
Periods.Any(p => check.ToDate >= p.FromDate && check.FromDate <= p.ToDate));
```

Comment: @Gabe, +1.  :-)  If this code is embedded in an ASP.NET file, and it is commented out with <!-- -->, then we'll have <!-- and --> in the same expression also!  Unfortunately I can't mix C/C++ code, otherwise I can also put in "->"...

Comment: The `->` operator in C# does the same thing as it does in C/C++ (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h(v=VS.80).aspx). Also, don't forget the `-->` and `<--` operators (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/01/somelastminutefeatures.aspx)!

Comment: @Gabe, I know, but it needs unmanaged (unsafe) code to use ->...  But that link on `-->` and `<--` are just *totally wild*!  +1

Answer (score 5):

If `FromDate <= ToDate` always holds true for your `Period` objects, you can define a helper [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) `OverlapsWith` as follows:

```
public static bool OverlapsWith(this Period a, Period b)
{
    return !(b.ToDate <= a.FromDate || a.ToDate <= b.FromDate);
}
```

To illustrate what's going on, let's look at the two cases where there is *no* overlap between `a` and `b`:

```
//                         a
//                |-----------------|
//   |--------|                          |-----------|
//       b1                                    b2
```

You can check the above condition against this diagram. Since the diagram shows the cases where no overlap occurs, but the method really ought to test *for* overlap, the condition needs to be negated. It could be simplified to the following:

```
           b.ToDate > a.FromDate && a.ToDate > b.FromDate
```

When you use this method in a LINQ query, it turns out very easy to understand:

```
    Periods.Any(period => period.OverlapsWith(periodToCheck))
```

Comment: Thanks, and this is exactly what Stephen Chung has written. `check.ToDate >= p.FromDate && check.FromDate <= p.ToDate`

Comment: @Homam, I'm aware of that, but I didn't just want to show a correct formula; I also wanted to explain the thinking behind it by a visual means. Second, I wanted to demonstrate that you get an easy-to-understand LINQ query with some expressive helper methods.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) useful and especially the `TimePeriodIntersector` class.

Sample excerpt:

```
public void TimePeriodIntersectorSample()
{
    TimePeriodCollection periods = new TimePeriodCollection();

    periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 01 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 10 ) ) );
    periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 05 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 15 ) ) );
    periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 12 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 18 ) ) );

    periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 20 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 24 ) ) );
    periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 22 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 28 ) ) );
    periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 24 ), new DateTime( 2011, 3, 26 ) ) );

    TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange> periodIntersector = 
                    new TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange>();
    ITimePeriodCollection intersectedPeriods = periodIntersector.IntersectPeriods( periods );

    foreach ( ITimePeriod intersectedPeriod in intersectedPeriods )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Intersected Period: " + intersectedPeriod );
    }
    // > Intersected Period: 05.03.2011 - 10.03.2011 | 5.00:00
    // > Intersected Period: 12.03.2011 - 15.03.2011 | 3.00:00
    // > Intersected Period: 22.03.2011 - 26.03.2011 | 4.00:00
} // TimePeriodIntersectorSample
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Do 2 periods having common date, say ToDate for period 1 and FromDate of period 2 are the same, count as in intersection ?

If yes then a little modification to your query to simply check the dates of a period if are within the checked period separately as if one of the dates falls inside a period then there is intersection:

```
bool conflict = Periods.Any(p => ((p.FromDate >= periodToCheck.fromDate && 
                                    p.ToDate <= periodToCheck.fromDate)
                                  ||
                                   (p.FromDate >= periodToCheck.toDate && 
                                    p.ToDate <= periodToCheck.toDate))
                             );
```